# Caffe CNN Slice layer: 2nd Slice layer produces unknown bottom blob

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

Caffe CNN Slice layer: 2nd Slice layer produces unknown bottom blob

I have 2 Slice layers (see proto file). It seems the 1st one is working well; whereas the 2nd one's bottom gives "unknown bottom blob error" as following:

In fact I am not sure the error is related to Slice or Flatten!? 
**please note that the the 2nd Slice does not even printed in the log!!!**

this is the Proto file:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label_b4_noise"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "data/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/2048_2e5_0.01_s_val_list.txt"
    batch_size: 25
    shuffle: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label_b4_noise"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "data/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/2048_2e5_0.01_s_train_list.txt"
    batch_size: 25
    shuffle: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "slic0"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "data1"
  top: "data2"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_u0d-score_New"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data1"
  top: "conv_last"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 1
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "msra"
    }
   }
}
layer {
  name: "flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv_last"
  top: "ampl"
}
layer {
  name: "slic1"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "label_b4_noise"
  top: "label_b4_noise1"
  top: "label_b4_noise2"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "flatdata"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "label_b4_noise1"
  top: "flatdata"
}

layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "ampl"
  bottom: "flatdata"
  top: "loss"
  softmax_param {engine: CAFFE}
}
```

this is the log file:

```
GL  ----------------------------------------------------------------
res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet data/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/2048_2e5_0.01_s .
res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet data/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/2048_2e5_0.01_s .
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I1018 11:40:22.930601 104201 upgrade_proto.cpp:67] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated input fields: res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet_tmp/unet_deploy.txt
I1018 11:40:22.930654 104201 upgrade_proto.cpp:70] Successfully upgraded file specified using deprecated input fields.
W1018 11:40:22.930658 104201 upgrade_proto.cpp:72] Note that future Caffe releases will only support input layers and not input fields.
I1018 11:40:23.237383 104201 net.cpp:51] Initializing net from parameters:
name: "unet"
state {
  phase: TEST
  level: 0
}
layer {
  name: "input"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
      dim: 2
      dim: 1
      dim: 2048
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "slic0"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "data1"
  top: "data2"
  slice_param {
    slice_point: 1
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_u0d-score_New"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data1"
  top: "conv_last"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 1
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "msra"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv_last"
  top: "ampl"
}
layer {
  name: "flatdata"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "label_b4_noise1"
  top: "flatdata"
}
F1018 11:40:23.237546 104201 insert_splits.cpp:29] Unknown bottom blob 'label_b4_noise1' (layer 'flatdata', bottom index 0)
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
/pbs/home/n/nhatami/sps/spectro/trainAndTest_4removal: line 101: 104201 Aborted                 $pydir/dumpLayersSize.py ${tmp_root}_deploy.txt ${oroot}

/pbs/home/n/nhatami/sps/spectro/trainAndTest_4removal: line 101: 104201 Aborted                 $pydir/dumpLayersSize.py ${tmp_root}_deploy.txt ${oroot}
Thu Oct 18 11:40:23 CEST 2018
/usr/bin/time -v caffe -gpu 0 --log_dir=res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet_tmp train -solver res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet_tmp/unet_solver.txt
Thu Oct 18 11:41:26 CEST 2018
/pbs/home/n/nhatami/sps/spectro/trainAndTest_4removal: line 206: gnuplot: command not found
/pbs/home/n/nhatami/sps/spectro/trainAndTest_4removal: line 225: gnuplot: command not found
/usr/bin/time -v -o res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet_time_test.txt python /pbs/home/n/nhatami/sps/spectro/python/test_4removal.py -eg hist -l label -mf=data/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/2048_2e5_0.01_s_met.txt res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet_deploy.txt res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet.caffemodel data/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/2048_2e5_0.01_s_test.h5 res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/restest/unet_test
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
W1018 11:41:42.595289 105177 _caffe.cpp:139] DEPRECATION WARNING - deprecated use of Python interface
W1018 11:41:42.595335 105177 _caffe.cpp:140] Use this instead (with the named "weights" parameter):
W1018 11:41:42.595338 105177 _caffe.cpp:142] Net('res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet_deploy.txt', 1, weights='res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet.caffemodel')
I1018 11:41:42.597472 105177 upgrade_proto.cpp:67] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated input fields: res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet_deploy.txt
I1018 11:41:42.597497 105177 upgrade_proto.cpp:70] Successfully upgraded file specified using deprecated input fields.
W1018 11:41:42.597501 105177 upgrade_proto.cpp:72] Note that future Caffe releases will only support input layers and not input fields.
I1018 11:41:42.597535 105177 net.cpp:51] Initializing net from parameters:
name: "unet"
state {
  phase: TEST
  level: 0
}
layer {
  name: "input"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
      dim: 2
      dim: 1
      dim: 2048
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "slic0"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "data1"
  top: "data2"
  slice_param {
    slice_point: 1
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_u0d-score_New"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data1"
  top: "conv_last"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 1
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "msra"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv_last"
  top: "ampl"
}
layer {
  name: "flatdata"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "label_b4_noise1"
  top: "flatdata"
}
F1018 11:41:42.597617 105177 insert_splits.cpp:29] Unknown bottom blob 'label_b4_noise1' (layer 'flatdata', bottom index 0)
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
('res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet_deploy.txt', 'res/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/unet_bs10/unet.caffemodel', 'data/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/2048_2e5_0.01_s_test.h5', 'data/4removal_nAmp3nData2_2e5/2048_2e5_0.01_s_met.txt')
```

here is h5disp:

```
Dataset 'label_b4_noise' 
        Size:  2048x1x2x10000
        MaxSize:  2048x1x2xInf
        Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
        ChunkSize:  2048x1x2x100
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0.000000

Dataset 'data' 
        Size:  2048x1x2x10000
        MaxSize:  2048x1x2xInf
        Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
        ChunkSize:  2048x1x2x100
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0.000000
```

Comment: can you please make a **minimal** example: only data layer and two slice layers. In that case, does caffe stil ignores the second one? what happens if you switch places between the two slice layers? is there a problem with the second one, or is there a problem slicing a specific input?

Comment: hi @shai I updated the post with a minimal example.

Comment: i figured the problem is with "label_b4_noise" in .h5 file. but i dont know what is the problem. this is h5disp:

Dataset 'label_b4_noise' 
        Size:  2048x1x2x10000
        MaxSize:  2048x1x2xInf
        Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
        ChunkSize:  2048x1x2x100
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0.000000

Comment: but it exactly same as "data"!! when I replace "label_b4_noise" (in proto) with "data", all is fine!

Comment: is the h5disp output for **both** train and test hdf5 files? can you narrow the error to either train/test phase with only data and slice layers?